# Why is Calendar class (Java) resetting its fields?

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I am trying to set properties for a Calendar class instance. But each time I get to Dec 30, it resets to  the next year. Is this a draw in the Calendar class?

```
public Calendar setCalendar()
{
    String Date = "2013-12-30";
    int yyyy = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,4));
    int mm = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(5,7));
    int dd = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(8,10));
    System.out.println(yyyy + " " + mm + " " + dd);
    Calendar Cal= new GregorianCalendar();
    Cal.set(yyyy,mm,dd);
    System.out.println(Cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+","+Cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    return Cal;
}
```

Output:
2013 12 30
2014,0

Comment: I recommend simplifying your code and seeing if it still appears to give the same perceived behavior.  Your `date.substring` code looks fishy to me.  It looks like your substrings will include '-'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Calendar` the months are 0-based, so you're actually setting the month to next year's January.

If you really need to use a `Calendar` I recommend at least using a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse your `String` to a `Date` and setting the calendar using that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Calendar API doc, month value is 0 based i.e Jan is 0.

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

You are setting month to 12. This effectively gives you the next year. To correct try:

```
Cal.set(yyyy,mm-1,dd);
```

Hope that helps